# How do I find all the code/files/modules belong to a particular feature in PostgreSQL source code?

Tags: postgresql, database-design

Suppose I want to see the complete code written for the feature "Text Search Configuration" in PostgreSQL source code, How do I get it?

Debugging is one way but that may not be sufficient and I may do it wrong.

Please let me know if there is a way to find it for each feature. 
Or is this a wrong approach to look at the PostgreSQL code?

Basically I want to know what it takes to implement a new feature and what all components/files are to be modified for that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clone the source code from git, then `git grep`. That'll usually help you find what you're looking for. There's also documentation on PostgreSQL's internals and structure; see the developer section of the PostgreSQL website and wiki. Some subsystems have `README` files in the source tree, and there are comments everywhere.

For example:

```
git grep 'tsearch' src/
```

quickly shows that you're looking for `src/backend/tsearch` and `src/include/tsearch` in this  case, as well as `src/backend/utils/adt/ts*`, and `src/backend/commands/tsearchcmds.c`.

"tsearch" is the internal name of the feature.

---

If you didn't know that you'd be able to find it with something like:

```
git grep 'TEXT.*SEARCH' src/
```

to look for the text search SQL commands. That'd lead you to `src/backend/parser/gram.y`, the parser grammar, and `src/backend/commands/tsearchcmds.c`.

If you look it up in the parser grammar you'll find at around line 5130:

```
                      | CREATE TEXT_P SEARCH CONFIGURATION any_name definition
                              {
                                      DefineStmt *n = makeNode(DefineStmt);
                                      n->kind = OBJECT_TSCONFIGURATION;
                                      n->args = NIL;
                                      n->defnames = $5;
                                      n->definition = $6;
                                      $$ = (Node *)n;
                              }
```

which shows the creation of a parse-node of type `OBJECT_TSCONFIGURATION`. So you can look for `OBJECT_TSCONFIGURATION`:

```
$ git grep OBJECT_TSCONFIGURATION
src/backend/catalog/objectaddress.c:            "text search configuration", OBJECT_TSCONFIGURATION
src/backend/catalog/objectaddress.c:                    case OBJECT_TSCONFIGURATION:
src/backend/catalog/objectaddress.c:            case OBJECT_TSCONFIGURATION:
src/backend/commands/alter.c:           case OBJECT_TSCONFIGURATION:
src/backend/commands/alter.c:           case OBJECT_TSCONFIGURATION:
src/backend/commands/alter.c:           case OBJECT_TSCONFIGURATION:
src/backend/commands/dropcmds.c:                case OBJECT_TSCONFIGURATION:
src/backend/commands/event_trigger.c:           case OBJECT_TSCONFIGURATION:
src/backend/parser/gram.y:                                      n->objtype = OBJECT_TSCONFIGURATION;
src/backend/parser/gram.y:                                      n->kind = OBJECT_TSCONFIGURATION;
src/backend/parser/gram.y:                      | TEXT_P SEARCH CONFIGURATION                   { $$ = OBJECT_TSCONFIGURATION; }
src/backend/parser/gram.y:                      | TEXT_P SEARCH CONFIGURATION           { $$ = OBJECT_TSCONFIGURATION; }
src/backend/parser/gram.y:                                      n->renameType = OBJECT_TSCONFIGURATION;
src/backend/parser/gram.y:                                      n->objectType = OBJECT_TSCONFIGURATION;
src/backend/parser/gram.y:                                      n->objectType = OBJECT_TSCONFIGURATION;
src/backend/tcop/utility.c:                                             case OBJECT_TSCONFIGURATION:
src/backend/tcop/utility.c:             case OBJECT_TSCONFIGURATION:
src/backend/tcop/utility.c:                             case OBJECT_TSCONFIGURATION:
src/backend/tcop/utility.c:                             case OBJECT_TSCONFIGURATION:
src/include/nodes/parsenodes.h: OBJECT_TSCONFIGURATION,
```

From here there are a few paths to find what you really want. For example, the `standard_ProcessUtility` function in `utility.c` calls `DefineTSConfiguration` in `src/backend/commands/tsearchcmds.c` for `case OBJECT_TSCONFIGURATION`. You can find the function's location with `git grep` or (better) using cscope or ctags, preferably via your text editor's C editing integration.

---

That file contains commands manipulating the tsearch configuration, but not the implementation of fulltext search. If that's what you wanted, you'd instead start by looking for the C implementations of `to_tsvector` and `to_tsquery`. Searching for those will lead you to `src/backend/tsearch/to_tsany.c`, putting you where you need to be looking.

Sometimes the C function name is different to the SQL function name. In this case you'll only find a `pg_proc.h` entry, and that'll tell you the C function name to look up. In this case the C and SQL function names are the same so you don't need to go through `pg_proc.h`.

---

So, in general, the idea is to *learn to navigate large bodies of code* using `git grep` and `cscope` (or your text editor's equivalent code navigation features).

Start from the SQL-visible entry point if you don't know what it's called or where to look. Look in the parser grammar `gram.y`, then look at what uses the parse nodes it produces. Look at the SQL-level functions (`pg_proc.h`) and operators (`pg_operator.h`) that implement the feature, and follow them to the source code. grep for references to it in the code tree or follow call chains.

Understanding the high level structure helps a lot, and that's where the talks, slides and other documents on the developer section of the PostgreSQL website and wiki will help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot Craig for the detailed answer.